# Spring Cloud Feign Clients don't connect with a different Context Roots for different instances

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign, netflix-eureka

I am in the process of evaluating Spring cloud with Eureka and the Feign Client with Ribbon.
My sample application I've been creating has a Eureka Server that receives the Clients just fine.

However, when using the FeignClient, the RequestMapping requires the Context Path to be included.

In my initial case, I had two services with the same VIP but different IDs.
- one service at localhost:8080/
- one service at localhost:7400/HelloWorld

The reason for the different context roots is due to potential deployment structure I can't easily change.

Is this something I need to configure within my Client? or Application or is this not possible?

Here is my @FeignClient

```
<code>

@Autowired
HelloClient client;

@FeignClient(value = "Hello-World")
interface HelloClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/HelloWorld", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String hello();
}

</code>
```

Ideally, the RequestMapping would only be the value '/'

Comment: I'm a little confused at your setup.  You have two services on the same host (localhost:8080/ and localhost:7400/HelloWorld), correct?  You will need two different FeignClients, one for each service.

Comment: They are currently on the same host. However, they could just as easily be different hosts.

They each register with Eureka as the same service and they each have a different server.context-path.
However, this seems to be ignored when the FeignClient attempts to connect to the service.

Comment: Feign knows nothing about the remote services server.context-path.  How is any client, regardless of Feign, going to know how to connect to your services with different context paths?

Comment: I guess based on what I see and what you are saying, Eureka through Feign expect everything to be with a context root of '/'
Anything else needs to be explicitly specified in the configuration of the Feign client.

It would be useful if through Eureka, it would be possible to specify the context root for the service.

Comment: I guess I'm still questioning why multiple instances of the same service will have different context-paths?  You could put context-path in the eureka meta-data, similar to [how we do instanceId](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/customers-stores/blob/master/rest-microservices-store/src/main/resources/application.yml#L18-L22)

Comment: Is it easy for a client to use the meta-data in a generic manner?
Basically the reason this is important is we are currently required to deploy to WebLogic. We are looking at a solution using CloudFoundry or something similar.  Our goal is to not need to carry the Context-Root issue for the life of the software and would like to avoid special software coding.

Comment: It would be an enhancement.

Comment: What about implementation of zuul with reverse proxy. You can easily mange your routes. Then you can talk with each other services.